# Why does htop show 430% CPU?

Tags: linux, htop

I'm confused by the CPU% values of this multi-threaded program.
Is 430% the sum of all threads?
If so, how do I find out the CPU% of the main thread itself (1776)?

```
  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
 1776 forge      20   0 4686M  101M 10616 R 430.  0.6  2:03.66 /srv/backend/backend --conf-file /srv/backend/join.conf
 1892 forge      20   0 4686M  101M 10616 R  9.9  0.6  0:00.85 /srv/backend/backend --conf-file /srv/backend/join.conf 
 1895 forge      20   0 4686M  101M 10616 R  7.9  0.6  0:00.83 /srv/backend/backend --conf-file /srv/backend/join.conf 
 1849 forge      20   0 4686M  101M 10616 R  7.9  0.6  0:00.79 /srv/backend/backend --conf-file /srv/backend/join.conf 
 1886 forge      20   0 4686M  101M 10616 S  7.9  0.6  0:00.85 /srv/backend/backend --conf-file /srv/backend/join.conf 
 1840 forge      20   0 4686M  101M 10616 S  7.9  0.6  0:00.80 /srv/backend/backend --conf-file /srv/backend/join.conf 
 1872 forge      20   0 4686M  101M 10616 R  7.9  0.6  0:00.82 /srv/backend/backend --conf-file /srv/backend/join.conf 
 1850 forge      20   0 4686M  101M 10616 R  7.9  0.6  0:00.79 /srv/backend/backend --conf-file /srv/backend/join.conf 
 1834 forge      20   0 4686M  101M 10616 S  7.9  0.6  0:00.77 /srv/backend/backend --conf-file /srv/backend/join.conf
```

Comment: To enable thread views in htop, launch htop, and press <F2> to enter htop setup menu. Choose "Display option" under "Setup" column, and toggle on "Three view" and "Show custom thread names" options. Presss <F10> to exit the setup.

Comment: @DanilaLadner Thanks but how's that related to my question? I know about tree view.